# Usage "a grade of"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say, "I expect to graduate with a grade of 3.4 to 3.5".

I was told that if I use "of", I should not follow it with a range (x to y) but rather with a specific number.

Comment: You were either misinformed or you misunderstood what you were told. Can you give links to any support for this bizarre assertion?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was told that in person and I thought it was strange as well.

Comment: In that case I suppose we have to assume that whoever told you this was either misinformed or misunderstood what *they* were told by someone else (we'll discard the possibility that they were just winding you up). I can't imagine *why* anyone would think this (imho, it's a daft idea), but perhaps someone else here on ELU knows more about it.

Comment: I kind of get where the other person who told you this is coming from. As a compromise I'd say "a grade of between 3.4 and 3.5."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is better to call a numerical grade "[***GPA***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grade_point_average)" which stands for Grade Point Average:

> A method of computing a numerical value for letter grades received in
>   school by assigning each a numeric value and averaging the numbers.

[Wiktionary]

Secondly, if you need to include a range, it is better to specify it by saying:

> "I expect to graduate with a [GPA range](http://www.hpplc.indiana.edu/ohp/GPArange.shtml) of 3.4 to 3.5".

Or if you want to use a GPA or a grade, use "or" in place of "to":

> "I expect to graduate with a GPA (a grade) of 3.4 ***or*** 3.5.

Or use "approximately (or its synonyms such as around, about, etc)":

> I expect to graduate with a GPA (a grade) of ***approximately*** 3.4.

Comment: Why do you need to put in *"range"*? It's totally unnecessary, and it's better just to leave it out. Nobody says *tomorrow, we expect the temperature range to be 25° to 30°*. Ditto for GPA. They might say *The temperatures in Boston in March can range from -10° to 25°C.* But that feels different to me.

Comment: @PeterShor I can understand why you are raising this issue, but there is a big difference. Temperature changes by the hour/minute/second. GPA doesn't.